# How to adding personal information link to QR code

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

The user will register with the name surname and id on the site. Then there will be an ID for this user, for example 1, which will be available on the website www.mywebsite / id1.com. For each user, www.website/id1 QR code will occur at the same time. How do I do that?

I tried another method, but there is a problem: `$text="http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/<?= session.userID ?>`

I create user with the mysql database
but the qr code give the link like `http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/<?= session.userID ?` as you see it gives by string value

but i want to it give like this `http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/userid2`

How can I solve ?

```
<?php
  require "header.php";
  require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
  $path='img/';
  $file = $path.uniqid().".png";
  $text="http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/<?= session.userID ?>";
?>

    <main>
      <div class="wrapper-main">
        <section class="section-default">

          <?php

          if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
            echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
          }
          else if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
            echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
               QRcode::png($text,$file,'L',10,2);
            echo "<center><img src='".$file."'></center> " ; 


}
          ?>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>

<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from the upper block

```
$text="http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/<?= session.userID ?>";
```

and move it there as

```
else if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
    $text="http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/userid{$_SESSION['userID']}";
    echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
        QRcode::png($text,$file,'L',10,2);
    echo "<center><img src='".$file."'></center> " ;
```

> but i want to it give like this
>   `http://localhost/nodemcu_project_template/userid2`

I followed your assumption that the `id` is `1` or otherwise an integer. You wished the link to have the literal text `userid`. Be sure to tweak it to return what you actually need.